# PHP Xdebug error unknown 'felixfbecker.php-debug' extension

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

I have follow the link : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug to install **Xdebug** debugging with PHP on Visual Studio Code. But, i keep getting this error.

```
Cannot activate the 'PHP Xdebug' extension because it depends on an unknown 'felixfbecker.php-debug' extension.
```

In *php.ini*

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

In *settings.json*

```
"php.debug.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
```

In *launch.json*

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch built-in server and debug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-S",
                "localhost:8000",
                "-t",
                "."
            ],
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug current script in console",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
```

Does anyone has the solution or explain why?

Comment: `'felixfbecker.php-debug'` is the *old* name of this extension. Are you sure you have not also installed that?